# ui-sref set child view to parent view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ui-sref

I am using ui-sref for routing depending upon state.
Currently I am getting child's view inside parent as hierarchy. I want to assign a child's view to a parent view. Current state is as below `plunker`.

[link][//plnkr.co/edit/fpsTWglicbcGMotJIlll]

I want to see welcome after clicking click me.

Comment: your js file doesn't have any code in it, please share your code here on Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: I am not able to add hyper link ..I am adding plain URL .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the problem is you have inner as a child of tab1... so it is displayed in the ui-view of tab1.  If you want it instead to make it replace tab1, then you don't need the ui-view in tab1.

Here's a forked plunker showing what I mean.

http://plnkr.co/edit/t4cxejVLGf4kywKp2bb5?p=preview

The parts I changed:

```
.state("main", { abtract: true, url:"/main", templateUrl:"main.html" })
.state("main.tab1", { url: "/tab1", templateUrl: "tab1.html" })
.state("main.inner",{
  url:"/inner",
  templateUrl:"inner.html"
})
.state("main.tab2", { url: "/tab2", templateUrl: "tab2.html" })
```

And in tab1.html

```
<div>
    This is the view for tab1
    <a ui-sref="main.inner">click me</a>
</div>
```

Is this what you're shooting for?

Comment: Thanks ..I will incorporate this with my module.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$scope.$state = $state;`in the controller.

Then add `ng-hide="$state.current.name === 'main.tab1.inner'"` to

```
 <h2 ng-hide="$state.current.name === 'main.tab1.inner'">View:</h2>
```

and

```
<div ng-hide="$state.current.name === 'main.tab1.inner'">
This is the view for tab1
<a ui-sref="main.tab1.inner">click me</a>
</div>
```

Here's the link [link] http://plnkr.co/edit/Yvlp6RNF69yiSq1HfMcf?p=preview

Comment: Thaks for efforts and time,This is also looks fine but I am looking for something like @DWDuck  mentioned.